# How to find $a_j$ that minimizes $\sum_{j=1}^J a_j^2 b_j + (\sum_{j=1}^J a_j c_j)^2$

Tags: calculus, optimization

Suppose $b_j, c_j \in \mathbb{R}$ are constants (for $j = 1, \ldots, J$). I would like to minimize the following objective function wrt $a_j, j = 1, \ldots, J$.

$$\sum_{j=1}^J a_j^2 b_j + \left(\sum_{j=1}^J a_j c_j\right)^2$$

Taking the partial derivative wrt $a_k$, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial a_k} \left[\sum_{j=1}^J a_j^2 b_j + \left(\sum_{j=1}^J a_j c_j\right)^2 \right]&= 2a_kb_k + 2c_k\left(\sum_{j=1}^J a_j c_j\right)\\
&\overset{set}{=} 0\\
\Longrightarrow a_kb_k &= -c_k\sum_{j=1}^J a_j c_j\\
a_k &= \frac{-c_k\sum_{j=1}^J a_j c_j}{b_k}
\end{align*}

Is the above correct? Is it okay for $a_k$ to be a function of $\sum_{j=1}^J a_jc_j$? The reason I'm thrown off is that I'm trying to find the optimal $a_k$, but it looks like the optimal $a_k$ still depends on itself through $\sum_{j=1}^J a_jc_j$

Comment: You shouldn't use $j$ as summation index if you have $j$ already as a fixed index. As a consequence I think the derivative of the second sum is wrong. Maybe you should first fix those issues. Edit: Also parentheses after the $\frac{\partial}{\partial a_j}$ would be helpful to clear, that you are derivating both sums.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your first point. I'm trying to find $a_1, \ldots, a_J$  that minimizes the objective function.

Comment: Look what happens, if you compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial a_1}(a_1^2b_1+a_2^2b_2+(a_1c_1+a_2c_2)^2)$ and compare it to the formula you have derived for the case $J=2$.

Comment: @GrafZahl Thanks, I've modified the original post.

Comment: I'm not a hundred percent sure, but this is a homogenous system of linear equations, so under some independence conditions $0$ would be the only solution. You could try to write $\sum_{j=1}^Ja_jc_j=-\frac{a_1b_1}{c_1}$ (for $c_1\neq 0$),and look what happens, if you plug this into the formula for $a_2,\dots,a_n$. They will only depend on $a_1$. Plugging in those $a_2,\dots,a_n$ into the sum, what would you obtain for $a_1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "solution depends on itself" effect just means that you end up with a system of linear equations that you need to solve to find a stationary point. In itself that's not a problem, just a matter of linear algebra.

In this case you don't even need to do much linear algebra -- since your equations have no constant terms, you can see immediately that $a_j=0$ for all $j$ will be a solution.

Indeed setting all $a_j$s to $0$ will make your objective function zero, which is a global minimum if all of your $b_j$s are positive or zero.

If there's one or more *negative* $b_j$, then either setting all the $a_j$s to zero will produce a minmum, or there's no minimum at all; that case will require further investigation involving the *second* derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite the stationarity condition as

$$\sum_{j=1}^{J} \left(2a_j b_j \delta_{jk} + 2 c_k a_j c_j\right) = 0$$

Where $\delta_{jk}$ is the Kronecker delta. Reordering and losing the 2:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{J} \left[\left(b_j \delta_{jk} + c_j c_k\right) a_j\right] = 0$$

If we let $M_{nj} = b_j \delta_{jk} + c_j c_k$, we get a matrix multiplication equation:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{J} M_{nj} a_j = 0$$

or

$$\mathbf{M}\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{0}$$

If $\mathbf{M}$ is non-singular, then $\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{0}$ is the only stationary point. Otherwise, the function has the additional stationary points whenever $\mathbf{a}$ is equal to a vector in the null space of $\mathbf{M}$. However, the stationary points can only be minimal if $\mathbf{M}$ is positive definite, which in turn is invertible.

Therefore, we can only get a minimum if $\mathbf{M}$ is positive definite, and that minimum is $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{0}$.